# Double "x rows affected" Message after UPDATE Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I only expected 159 rows to change - why I get this strange Message-Output with double affected lines?

[image: Output]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.  Your image has a single `update` statement.  Yet when you run it, you seem to get four different sets of rows that are updated.

Why would this happen?  The output suggests that your table has an `update` trigger.  It is the trigger that is responsible for the the additional rows.

Of course, your script could have multiple `update`s as well -- code that you are not showing.  But triggers would explain why a single `update` would result in multiple such messages.

Comment: I have no hidden code - the statement which I have posted, was executed by me and no code or triggers more than this

Comment: @Hopper . . . There are triggers on the table, it would seem.  Or I suppose it is possible that cascading update foreign key constraints might also result in this behavior in some databases.